# How can I boost a particular field using Sitecore 7.5 and Solr 4.7?

Tags: sitecore, solr4, sitecore7, sitecore7.5, boosting

I have a field called "Page Title" that is part of a base template that I called "Base Titles".  All of my content pages inherit this base template.  I would like to boost the Page Title field in my search results so that if the search term is found in that field it is scored higher than other matches.

I can't figure out how to do this. I found [this blog post by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-six-types-of-search-boosting.aspx).  However that seems to suggest that in order to boost a field I have to edit a config file?

Is that correct?  So there is no way within the Sitecore UI to edit boosting values for a field?  It has to be done by a programmer in a config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built functionality for this. But off the top of my head I guess it's possible to approximate it.

For example. If your content editors have access to the Templates section of the Sitecore tree you could extend the `"Template Field"` template. Add a numeric field called `Boost`.

Then on any field in a template they could assign a numeric value

When you write your query you could look up the assigned value from of the associated field in the template and use the [Boost method](http://www.mattburkedev.com/lucene-boost-with-linq-in-sitecore-7-contentsearch/) to apply it to the predicate.

Of course there's a bunch of different variations on this approach. This is really just the bare bones.

Sounds like you have the makings of a good marketplace module on your hands.

Comment: So I notice if I navigate to a particular field in a template in the Sitecore tree there is a section called "Indexing" and there is a field called "Boost Value".  What is that used for?

Comment: 'Boost Value' is used to boost an entire item. it happens to be on every item because it's part of the standard template. You can read about it here: https://doc.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Search%20and%20indexing/Search%20result%20boosting. In theory you could repurpose this field for the idea I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. I read that link that you provided. This is my continuing frustration with Sitecore documentation. The top part of the article says "You use field-level boosting to specify that matches on some fields are more or less important than matches on other fields".  That's exactly what I want to do.  However nothing in the article below actually shows you how to do that!  It just shows you the different pipelines.  It doesn't really give you an example of how to do field level boosting.  So frustrating.

Comment: Also, that article that you linked to DOES seem to suggest that the pipeline eventually gets the boost value from that "Boost Value" field that I mentioned above.  "The FieldDefinitionItemResolver processor resolves the field-definition item that provides the boost value.

Once the template definition item has been resolved, the StaticFieldBoostResolver is started. This processor reads the boost value from the field-definition item."

Comment: @CoreyBurnett I share the same feelings - very frustrating